# I need an unordered list without any bullets

Tags: html, css

I have created an unordered list. I feel the bullets in the unordered list are bothersome, so I want to remove them.

Is it possible to have a list without bullets?

Answer (score 4162, accepted):

You can remove bullets by setting the [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) to `none` on the CSS for the parent element (typically a `<ul>`), for example:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

You might also want to add `padding: 0` and `margin: 0` to that if you want to remove indentation as well.

See [Listutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/index.htm) for a great walkthrough of list formatting techniques.

Comment: @tovmeod Seems to work fine in my IE9 (on Win7). (it is a complex page, not a simple POC, maybe something else changed the behavior)

Comment: If you are like me and also looking for how to remove the indent, see this -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13939142/846727

Comment: Nice touch on padding and margins

Comment: There is a much more elegant solution to display lists without bullets in the answer by @shaneb below. It makes use of the HTML5 object 'Description Lists'.

Comment: Bonus: you might need to add `padding-inline-start: 0` if you want to get rid of the left margin.

Comment: Beware that this also removes the list character for assistive technology, and will render your list way more difficult to navigate for users with disabilities—if it is a legitimate list, that is!

Comment: In JS it is `ul.style.listStyleType = "none"`

Comment: using django I went to base.css and changed  to ul > li {
    list-style-type: none; 
    padding: 1px 0;
}

li ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style-type: none; 
}

Answer (score 728):

If you're using Bootstrap, it has an "unstyled" class:

> Remove the default list-style and left padding on list items (immediate children only).

#### Bootstrap 2:

```
<ul class="unstyled">
   <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#typography

#### Bootstrap 3, 4, and 5:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
   <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Bootstrap 3: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-lists

Bootstrap 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/typography/#unstyled

Bootstrap 5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/typography/#unstyled

Comment: If we listed classes for every CSS framework, we would have a mess on StackOverflow.  A quick Google search reveals Bootstrap was only used by 2% of websites at its peak, and surely that's falling with the introduction of more sensible solutions like flexbox and css grid.

Comment: Actually, this answer is exactly what I was looking for.  And Bootstrap is used by 3.6% of the entire Internet, so it's not falling.  https://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/Twitter-Bootstrap  A quick Google search reveals that Bootstrap is consistently placed in the "most popular CSS frameworks" category.

Comment: @PJBrunet If we listed classes for every CSS framework, we would have much more people getting answers to their questions. Moreover, the OP didn't mention that he's interested only in a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Instead of class I would use id here if ul is unique. If not, stay with class.

Answer (score 229):

You need to use `list-style: none;`

```
<ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Be aware that inline css overrules css in files. Depending on the application/development practices it can be really annoying.

Answer (score 52):

Small refinement to the previous answers: To make longer lines more readable if they spill over to additional screen lines:

```css
ul, li {list-style-type: none;}

li {padding-left: 2em; text-indent: -2em;}
```

Comment: Works, but only for IE8

Comment: It's unnecessary to put `list-style-type: none;` on both the `ul` and the `li`. You can just do one.

Answer (score 21):

If you're unable to make it work at the `<ul>` level, you might need to place the `list-style-type: none;` at the `<li>` level:

```
<ul>
    <li style="list-style-type: none;">Item 1</li>
    <li style="list-style-type: none;">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

You can create a CSS class to avoid this repetition:

```
<style>
ul.no-bullets li
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
</style>

<ul class="no-bullets">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

When necessary, use `!important`:

```
<style>
ul.no-bullets li
{
    list-style-type: none !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Using !important is bad practice and unnecessary, if the code doesn't work make sure your new code is below the old one. In big projects when they want to make things dynamic !important can become very problematic.

Answer (score 15):

I used `list-style` on both the ul and the li to remove the bullets. I wanted to replace the bullets with a custom character, in this case a 'dash'. That gives a nicely indented effect that works fine when the text wraps.

```css
ul.dashed-list {
    list-style: none outside none;
}

ul.dashed-list li:before {
    content: "\2014";
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 -27px;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.dashed-list li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dashed-list">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you wanted to accomplish this with *pure* HTML alone, this solution will work across all major browsers:

**Description Lists**

Simply using the following HTML:

```html
    <dl>
      <dt>List Item 1</dt>
        <dd>Sub-Item 1.1</dd>
      <dt>List Item 2</dt>
        <dd>Sub-Item 2.1</dd>
        <dd>Sub-Item 2.2</dd>
        <dd>Sub-Item 2.3</dd>
      <dt>List Item 3</dt>
        <dd>Sub-Item 3.1</dd>
    </dl>
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/zumcmvma/2/

Reference here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp

Comment: If you're going to use this method, use the semantically proper way of entering a term to be defined in `<dt>` and the definition of that term in `<dd>`.

Comment: This is the best answer to the question, although the people who pose this question are unaware of this much more elegant solution, so they would dissagree, but this solution produces the best results.

Answer (score 7):

This orders a list vertically without bullet points. In just one line!

```css
li {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Technical note: this works because it overrides the default `display` value of `<li>`, which is `display: list-item;`.

Answer (score 4):

To completely remove the `ul` default style:

```css
list-style-type: none;

margin: 0;
margin-block-start: 0;
margin-block-end: 0;
margin-inline-start: 0;
margin-inline-end: 0;
padding-inline-start: 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are developing an existing theme, it's possible that the theme has a custom list style.

So if you can't change the list style using `list-style: none;` in ul or li tags, first check with `!important`, because maybe some other line of style is overwriting your style. If `!important` fixed it, you should find a more specific selector and clear out the `!important`.

```css
li {
    list-style: none !important;
}
```

If it's not the case, then check the `li:before`. If it contains the content, then do:

```css
li:before {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide them using [`::marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) pseudo-element.

1. Transparent `::marker`

---

```css
ul li::marker {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```css
ul li::marker {
  color: transparent;
}

ul {
  padding-inline-start: 10px; /* Just to reset the browser initial padding */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> Bullets are bothersome </li>
  <li> I want to remove them. </li>
  <li> Hey! ::marker to the rescue </li>
</ul>
```

2. `::marker` empty content

---

```css
ul li::marker {
  content: "";
}
```

```css
ul li::marker {
   content: "";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> Bullets are bothersome </li>
  <li> I want to remove them </li>
  <li> Hey! ::marker to the rescue </li>
</ul>
```

It is better when you need to remove bullets from a specific list item.

```css
ul li:nth-child(n)::marker { /* Replace n with the list item's position*/
   content: "";
}
```

```css
ul li:not(:nth-child(2))::marker {
   content: "";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> Bullets are bothersome </li>
  <li> But I can live with it using ::marker </li>
  <li> Not again though </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In **BOOTSTRAP** You can remove bullets by setting the **list-unstyled** class on the parent class of the li tag.

```
<ul className="list-unstyled">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Bootstrap is already covered in another answer.

Comment: className is only valid in ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul{list-style-type:none;}
```

Just set the style of unordered list is none.

Comment: Is there something new in this answer that wasn't already said?

Answer (score -1):

I tried and observed:

```
header ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually remove the bullets. They just get pushed off-screen.

Answer (score -2):

```
 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox left">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
         <label class="btn btn-secondary text-left" style="width:100%;text-align:left;padding:2px;">
           <input type="checkbox" style="zoom:1.7;vertical-align:bottom;" asp-for="@Model[i].IsChecked" class="custom-control-input" /> @Model[i].Title
         </label>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -8):

In case you want to keep things simple without resorting to CSS, I just put a `&nbsp;` in my code lines. I.e., `<table></table>`.

Yeah, it leaves a few spaces, but that's not a bad thing.

Comment: -1 Simple? Without CSS? This is why many websites are in the shocking state they are. CSS adds simplicity. Tables are not the way forward.