# Don't Display Numbers/Bullets for Ordererd or Unordered List

Tags: css

All,
I'm using the following code to generate some li items in an ol.

```
$output = '<div id="menu_options">';
$output .= '<ol class="tabs">';
foreach($menu_items as $menu){
    $output .= '<li><a href="'.$menu->ID.'" class="menu_page_id">'.$menu->title.'</a></li>';
}
$output .= '</ol>';
$output .= '</div>';
$output .= '<div id="menu_content">This is content</div>';
```

This works fine however I'd like to get rid of the 1., 2. etc. Is there a way to remove these and not display anything where these would typically go?

Comment: @PatrikAlienus: This is the first result on Google now. SO is a place to ask questions and get answers. If you find this question elsewhere on SO, mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus Indeed. Which is how I found this answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need an unordered list without any bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Yes, use a style property of `list-style-type:none` on the `ol`, either inline as a `style` attribute, or in your stylesheet under the `.tabs` class.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#lists

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show numbers in order list then use this CSS code. Write code for `className="disp"` `.disp{list-style-type:none;}` this code will not show any numbers.

```
<div className="disp">
    <ol>
        <li>Apple<li>
        <li>Mango<li>
        <li>Orange<li>
    </ol>
</div>
```