# Is it possible to partially list a HTML ordered list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an ordered list using CSS and the counter increment.  However I only want the first five items to show the counter:

Here is the code I currently have:

```js
    var myUnit_1 = 1;
    $(".demo1 li").css("counter-increment", "list " + myUnit_1);
```

```css
.demo1 {
    counter-reset: list;
}

.demo1 li:before {
    content: counter(list);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="demo1">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li>  Do not wish a number</li>
<li>  Do not wish a number</li>
<li>  Do not wish a number</li>
<li>  Do not wish a number</li>
</ul>
```

I need the list to be kept as one single list and not split in two parts.

Comment: The `u` in `ul` stands for "unordered" you know? If you want an ordered list, use `ol` and use CSS to remove the marker from the ones you don't want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't Display Numbers/Bullets for Ordererd or Unordered List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709758/dont-display-numbers-bullets-for-ordererd-or-unordered-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to partially list a HTML ordered list

Yes - and you don't need javascript for this.

> I am trying to create an ordered list

Start with `<ol>` - it's the ordered list element.

> I only want the first five items to show the counter

You can use a combination of `li:nth-of-type(n + 6)` and the CSS property `list-style-type`.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.demo1 li:nth-of-type(n + 6) {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ol class="demo1">
  <li>Number</li>
  <li>Number</li>
  <li>Number</li>
  <li>Number</li>
  <li>Number</li>
  <li>No number</li>
  <li>No number</li>
  <li>No number</li>
  <li>No number</li>
</ol>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- `<ol>` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol
- `:nth-of-type()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type
- `list-style-type` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to apply a selector to a range of elements:

```js
    var myUnit_1 = 1;
    $(".demo1 li").css("counter-increment", "list " + myUnit_1);
```

```css
.demo1 {
    counter-reset: list;
}

.demo1 li:nth-child(-n + 5):before {
    content: counter(list);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="demo1">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li>  Do not wish a number</li>
<li>  Do not wish a number</li>
<li>  Do not wish a number</li>
<li>  Do not wish a number</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @London28 – should be noted that you don't need any scripts for this, see answer below.