# How to remove indentation from an unordered list item?

Tags: html, css

I want to remove all indentation from `ul`. I tried setting `margin`, `padding`, `text-indent` to `0`, but no avail. Seems that setting `text-indent` to a negative number does the trick - but is that really the only way to remove the indentation?

Comment: Hard to say with out your HTML & CSS but using a CSS Reset/Normalize consisting of rules ul{padding: 0; margin: 0;} does the trick in most cases. I am sure text-indent has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Without seeing what you're actually doing, it's difficult to say what the problem is. Setting both margin and padding on the ul to 0 should work cross-browser.

Comment: "Didn't work. And can't use CSS reset. My changes are part of a giant web framework with over 60 people working on it haha" - Haha indeed. Than you have not asked your question clearly!

Answer (score 519, accepted):

Set the list style and left padding to nothing.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}​
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

To maintain the bullets you can replace the `list-style: none` with  `list-style-position: inside` or the shorthand `list-style: inside`:

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can remove the indents and keep the numbering/bullets by: ul { list-style-position: inside; padding-left: 0;}

Comment: Well, now that you edited your answer the bullets are maintained, but there is still the problem that <li>s with multiple text lines don't correctly indent all lines. It you keep on editing you may finally end up with my solution. :D

Comment: The second solution that keeps the bullet doesn't seem to work anymore (Chrome 55 on Windows). Any alternatives?

Comment: @TomPažourek Try `list-style-position: outside;
    padding-left: 1em;` on the `<ul>`

Comment: @j08691: Yeah, that works, although the `1em` thing is a bit of a magical value... And there's actually still a tiny bit of indentation left.

Comment: @TomPažourek I can elaborate about this magic "1em" a little bit further because I just stumbled about this myself. The idea behind this is to reduce the padding in such a way that the list items line up nicely with the rest of the text. Since we cannot really reduce the padding we just set the padding to account for the numbering of the items which is roughly 1em. The only problem is that this does not account for the actual padding of the other elements - hence the difference. Also, I guess it will probably stop working with bigger numbers.

Comment: Should we update the answer with logical properties: `padding-inline-start` instead of `padding-left`? We could keep the answer with `padding-left` explaining that it might be needed to be cross compatible with IE.

Answer (score 108):

My preferred solution to remove <ul> indentation is a simple CSS one-liner:

```css
ul { padding-left: 1.2em; }
```

```html
<p>A leading line of paragraph text</p>
<ul>
    <li>Bullet points align with paragraph text above.</li>
    <li>Long list items wrap around correctly. Long list items wrap around correctly. Long list items wrap around correctly. Long list items wrap around correctly. Long list items wrap around correctly. </li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
<p>A trailing line of paragraph text</p>
```

This solution is not only lightweight, but has multiple advantages:

- It nicely left-aligns <ul>'s bullet points to surrounding normal paragraph text (= indenting of <ul> removed).
- The text blocks within the <li> elements remain correctly indented if they wrap around into multiple lines.

---

**Legacy info:**
For IE versions 8 and below you must use margin-left instead:

```
    ul { margin-left: 1.2em; }
```

Comment: I explained all problems already in my posting, @aioobe. But here again: The accepted answer (status as of now, because after my original posting it has been edited multiple times to improve it) now maintains the bullets (if you use the second example given), but it does not correctly indent bulleted multiline text.  Here is the fiddle of the second example of the accepted answer, modified to show the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/v6nyuq6f/88/ And here is the same fiddle corrected with my approach: http://jsfiddle.net/v6nyuq6f/89/

Comment: So it's 2016 and relying on some value which is "not perfect for all browsers" is the cleanest solution for this pretty common problem. Is there any way to get the exact width of the item symbol, maybe using CSS3 features?

Comment: Just to be safe: `ul { padding-left:1.2em; margin-left: 0; }`

Comment: Only solution on this page, that works correctly with long list items (wrap around correctly) - Thanks!

Comment: A very nice solution.  As simple as it can be (I love simple).  I found that it does not seem to work as an inline style; but worked fine as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Add this to your CSS:

```
ul { list-style-position: inside; }
```

This will place the li elements in the same indent as other paragraphs and text.

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-position.asp

Comment: On <li>s with multiple text lines, ``list-style-position: inside`` aligns the text of the second and all following lines with the bullet. This is surely not desirable.

Answer (score 10):

`display:table-row;` will also get rid of the indentation but will remove the bullets.

Answer (score 7):

Remove the padding:

```
padding-left: 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you provide a link ?
thanks 
I can take a look 
Most likely your css selector isnt strong enough or can you try

`padding:0!important;`

Comment: Dimensions are not needed when specifying 0.

Comment: `!important` is *EVIL*

Comment: @Madbreaks It can work if the selector is the correct one and use case is correct but your right prob not this one, maybe in this case there is a main css rule that needs to be overridden with changing the base file, so it left in tack like not hacking core ? I dont know maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem with a footer I'm trying to divide up. I found that this worked for me by trying few of above suggestions combined:

```
footer div ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

This seems to keep it to the left under my h1 and the bullet points inside the div rather than outside to the left.

Answer (score 4):

Live demo: **https://jsfiddle.net/h8uxmoj4/**

```
ol, ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 1.25rem;
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

ol {
  counter-reset: counter;
}

ol li::before {
  content: counter(counter) ".";
  counter-increment: counter;
}

ul li::before {
  content: "●";
}
```

Since the original question is unclear about its requirements, I attempted to solve this problem within the guidelines set by other answers. In particular:

- Align list bullets with outside paragraph text
- Align multiple lines within the same list item

I also wanted a solution that didn't rely on browsers agreeing on how much padding to use. I've added an ordered list for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this inline, I set the margin to 0 (ul style="margin:0px"). The bullets align with paragraph with no overhang.

Comment: I don't understand why you were down-voted other than the negative sign in front of a zero.

I tried this on Google Chrome and it worked, whereas the padding-left: 0 solution did not. This is on Google Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88 WinX, 64 bit.

Comment: Adding to my comment above... since I can't edit it... I played with this a bit more, and on the latest Firefox (71.0), the behavior is the same. However, this is with unordered lists (ul). When using ordered lists (ol), 1.2em seems to align the left edge of the list with the left margin of other text (per Jpsy answer above).

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.
In Chrome, Edge and Firefox (which needs special treatment).
Bullets are kept and are on the same line with surrounding paragraphs.

```
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 17px;
}

/* Different value for Firefox */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  ul {
    margin-left: 14px;
  }
}
```