# How to reduce the indentation of <ul> tag in UILabel html attributedText?

Tags: html, ios, css, uilabel

I want to achieve this, notice the indentation of the list start with `•`.

[image: 111]

Here is the code:

```
   let src = // html
guard let data = memo.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode) else { return }
    do {
        content.attributedText = try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType:NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
```

HTML after beautified:

```html
   <p style="color: #333333;font-size:16px;"> And what is love? It is a doll dressed up
       And what is love? It is a doll dressed up </p> <p style="color: #333333;font-size:15px;">
            <div style="color: #333333;font-size:16px; margin: 0%; padding: 0%;  float: left;">And what is love? It is a doll dressed up</p>
                <p style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%; float: left;"> &#160• And what is love? It is a doll dressed up</p>
                    <p
                        style="float: left; -webkit-margin-before:0; -webkit-margin-after: 0; -webkit-margin-start: 0; -webkit-margin-end: 0; -webkit-padding-start:0">
                        &#160• And what is love? It is a doll dressed up</p>
                    <p style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%; float: left;"> &#160• And what is love? It is a doll dressed up</p>
                    <p style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%; float: left;"> &#160• And what is love? It is a doll dressed up</p>
                    <p style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%; float: left;"> &#160• And what is love? It is a doll dressed up</p>
                    <p style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%; float: left;"> &#160• And what is love? It is a doll dressed up</p>
            </div>
```

I achieved it by `&#160•`, it's tricky, not very html.

I want to achieve this with `ul` tag

Here is what I tried.

[image: 0]

Here is the code:

```
let src =  // html
```

HTML after beautified:

```html
 <p style="color: #333333;font-size:16px;">For idleness to cosset, nurse, and dandle;</p>
    <p style="color: #333333;font-size:15px;">For idleness to cosset, nurse, and dandle;</p>
    <ul style="color: #333333;font-size:16px; margin: 0%; padding: 0%;  float: left;">
        <li style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%; float: left;">For idleness to cosset, nurse, and dandle;</li>
        <li style="float: left; -webkit-margin-before:0; -webkit-margin-after: 0; -webkit-margin-start: 0; -webkit-margin-end: 0; -webkit-padding-start:0">
           For idleness to cosset, nurse, and dandle;</li>
        <li style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%; float: left;">For idleness to cosset, nurse, and dandle;</li>
        <li style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%; float: left;">For idleness to cosset, nurse, and dandle;</li>
        <li style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%; float: left;">For idleness to cosset, nurse, and dandle;</li>
        <li style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%; float: left;">For idleness to cosset, nurse, and dandle;</li>
    </ul>
```

**How to reduce the indentation of `<ul>` tag in UILabel attributedText?**

[more code on github](https://github.com/ForStackO/picker/tree/master/html)

I have seen [How to remove indentation from an unordered list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938975/how-to-remove-indentation-from-an-unordered-list-item/13939142)

`padding-left: 15px;` works perfectly for chrome, but not proper for UILabel

Comment: What do you mean with "not proper for UILabel"?

Comment: I mean, It doesn't work for `UILabel `. The css style did not take effect.