# Removing "bullets" from unordered list <ul>

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have set this:

```
list-style: none outside none;
```

And HTML:

```
<ul class="menu custompozition4">
    <li class="item-507"><a href=#">Strategic Recruitment Solutions</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-508"><a href="#">Executive Recruitment</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-509"><a href="#">Leadership Development</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-510"><a href="#">Executive Capability Review</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-511"><a href="#">Board and Executive Coaching</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-512"><a href="#">Cross Cultutral Coaching</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-513"><a href="#">Team Enhancement &amp; Coaching</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-514"><a href="#">Personnel Re-deployment</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but even though bullets are displayed. (I'm not quite sure that those are ul's bullets, because when you hover the text the "bullets" get underlined.)

Image Demo:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfkKZ.png

**The third level from the menu**

Comment: You should post your html here as well.  Links go bad over time.

Comment: it is better to change the accepted answer to that high up-voted post provided by @newtonrd as it is the actual simple answer. this can help people who searched this and reach here...

Comment: @S.Serp I have mentioned in my question that I tried setting `list-style-type` to `none`, but that didn't help. So, the answer that helped my problem is marked as accepted. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need an unordered list without any bullets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ul.menu li a:before, ul.menu li .item:before, ul.menu li .separator:before {
  content: "\2022";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Is present in your site's CSS, looks like it's coming from a compiled CSS file from within your application. Perhaps from a plugin. Changing the name of the "menu" class you are using should resolve the issue.

Visual for you - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qvax.png

Answer (score 199):

Have you tried setting

```
li {list-style-type: none;}
```

According to [Need an unordered list without any bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-a-unordered-list-without-any-bullets), you need to add this style to the li elements.

Comment: It's easier to add the style to the parent `<ul>`.

Answer (score 15):

You can remove the **"bullets"** by setting the **"list-style-type: none;"** Like

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

OR

```
<ul class="menu custompozition4"  style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li class="item-507"><a href=#">Strategic Recruitment Solutions</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-508"><a href="#">Executive Recruitment</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-509"><a href="#">Leadership Development</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-510"><a href="#">Executive Capability Review</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-511"><a href="#">Board and Executive Coaching</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-512"><a href="#">Cross Cultutral Coaching</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-513"><a href="#">Team Enhancement &amp; Coaching</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-514"><a href="#">Personnel Re-deployment</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case

```
li {
  list-style-type : none;
}
```

It doesn't show the bullet but leaved some space for the bullet.

I use

```
li {
  list-style-type : '';
}
```

It works perfectly.

Comment: This is not a valid CSS. You can remove the space by setting the padding or margin to 0.

Comment: I don't know why does it worked. But it worked in my case. @IvankaTodorova

Answer (score 2):

In your css file add following.

```
ul{
 list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use it this way to

```
               {
                Fdata.map((point,index) =>(
                  <ul style ={{listStyle:'none'}}key={index} >                  
                    
                    <li className="text_paragraph"style={{fontSize:"0.8rem",color:"#ff1100"}}>{point.list}</li>
                </ul>
                ))
                }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

Try this it works

```
<ul class="sub-menu" type="none">
           <li class="sub-menu-list" ng-repeat="menu in list.components">
               <a class="sub-menu-link">
                   {{ menu.component }}
               </a>
           </li>
        </ul>
```