# Removing bullets from unordered list

Tags: html, css

**Edit**

The html and css for the site I am working on can be found at http://http://new.oranaschool.com/

**/Edit**

I am trying to remove the bullets showing in the top horizontal menu (Home...Contact). I have tried the advice given in [Removing "bullets" from unordered list <ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028741/removing-bullets-from-unordered-list-ul) but still the bullets persist.

Can someone have a look at the CSS and tell me what I need to add to which CSS class? This has been driving me nuts now for a couple of hours.

Comment: You just need to use list-style: none; <ul style="list-style: none;"><li> ... That will remove the bullets.

Comment: You haven't provided any CSS...

Comment: ul li { list-style-type:none; }

Comment: @All Can you have a look at the URL I have posted? As you will see there are numerous CSS classes in play. Adding suggestions to .navigation ul.sf-menu has done nothing to improve things.

Comment: @TheEdge There is no URL in your post..other than to a SO question.

Comment: @Paulie_D Doh!!! Thanks for pointing that out. Man it has been a long day. I have now edited the post.

Comment: please add you code.. or quick fix is adding important  
ul li { list-style-type:none !important; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove background-image from this

```
.navigation ul.sf-menu > li:before {
     background: url(../images/menu_bull.png) 0 0 no-repeat; /** remove this */
}
```

and if you don't want to edit the original code add

```
.navigation ul.sf-menu > li:before {
         background: url('');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.ui-menu li {
    list-style:none;

}
ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
li
{
   display:inline;
    padding-left:14px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="ui-menu">
<ul>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Tea</li>
<li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/psgou7bt/2/

HTML

```
  <ul class="no-bullets">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    </ul>
```

Css

```
  .no-bullets, .no-bullets li {
        list-style-type:none;

    }
```

If this don't work for you, then you have some conflicts in your code

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue you are facing on the website. You can remove the bullets using below CSS.

```
.navigation ul.sf-menu > li::before {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Or remove the `background` completely from your stylesheet.

Comment: Can you have a look at the URL I have posted? As you will see there are numerous CSS classes in play. Adding suggestions to .navigation ul.sf-menu has done nothing to improve things.

Comment: @TheEdge, Add your HTML at least. Otherwise, any of our solution might not work on your html.

Comment: The HTML can be found at the posted URL namely http://new.oranaschool.com and then View Source

Answer (score 0):

You can remove bullets by using list-style-type to none on the CSS for the `<ul>` element, for example:

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you have a look at the URL I have posted? As you will see there are numerous CSS classes in play. Adding suggestions to .navigation ul.sf-menu has done nothing to improve things.

Comment: you just need to add the code in your css which i just posted, give it a try.

Comment: That will be for ALL unordered lists. I only want it for the top menu.

Comment: then give it some specific class then you can use it as .abc ul{list-style:none;}