# How do I remove the bullets and keep the rest of my html/css code from falling apart

Tags: html, css

The issue is with bullets in my html file.

I have already tried going to nav ul, the location I need to remove the bullet list and tried including list styles to remove them. Although this works, the formatting of my menu falls apart and I don't know either the cause or the fix for this. So instead I decided to leave the bullets in in the hopes that someone could find a solution for my issue. I've included the css and html code I'm working with. This is my first post so if there's anything I could do better when posting a question, please let me know.

```css
* {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    background:#b794e6ff;
}

h2{
    padding: 40px;
    background: #646ecb;
    color:#f0f1f5;
    font-family: fantasy;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30pt;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
}

.navbar {
    background: #fc575e;
    height: 40px;
    width:700px;
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13pt;
    color: aliceblue;
}

nav a:hover {
    background:#223423;
    color: #f0f1f5;
}


nav ul {
  display: block;
    
}

nav ul li {
    float:left;
    width:140px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background:teal;
}

nav ul ul li{
    position: relative;
    display:none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/maintravel2.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
       
   
      
      <title>Round-a-Whirl</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div></div>
           <h2>HEADER LOGO</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"> Flights</i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-hotel"> Hotel</i></a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car"> Car Rental</i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"> Discover</i></a>
                    <ul>
                    <li>Vacation</li>
                    <li>Cruise</li>
                    <li>City</li>
                    <li>Nature</li>
                    <li>Getaways</li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tag"> Deals</i></a></li>
                
                </ul>

            </nav>
      </div>
        <article>
        This is a simple site I created using HTML and CSS of a travel site for the fictional Round-a-Whirl travel company.
        </article>
        <footer>
            Round-a-Whirl &copy; 2019
        </footer>
      

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: set the list-style to be 'none' in the CSS file didn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing "bullets" from unordered list <ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028741/removing-bullets-from-unordered-list-ul)

Comment: The problem i'm having is an overlap from the drop down menu in the discover section . the top edge of the first drop down list goes through discover once I remove the bullets. For whatever reason, it works fine on the online editor but even after copying the answer to my own desktop editor the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add the style `list-style-type:none;` to the `<ul/>` in the `<nav/>`

This can be done as simply as adding this to your css:

```
.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Here is your updated page:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #b794e6ff;
}

h2 {
  padding: 40px;
  background: #646ecb;
  color: #f0f1f5;
  font-family: fantasy;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30pt;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
}

.navbar {
  background: #fc575e;
  height: 40px;
  width: 700px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13pt;
  color: aliceblue;
}

nav a:hover {
  background: #223423;
  color: #f0f1f5;
}

nav ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: teal;
}

nav ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/maintravel2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">



  <title>Round-a-Whirl</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div></div>
      <h2>HEADER LOGO</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="navbar">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"> Flights</i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-hotel"> Hotel</i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car"> Car Rental</i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"> Discover</i></a>
            <ul>
              <li>Vacation</li>
              <li>Cruise</li>
              <li>City</li>
              <li>Nature</li>
              <li>Getaways</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tag"> Deals</i></a></li>

        </ul>

      </nav>
    </div>
    <article>
      This is a simple site I created using HTML and CSS of a travel site for the fictional Round-a-Whirl travel company.
    </article>
    <footer>
      Round-a-Whirl &copy; 2019
    </footer>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type). It sets the "bullets" for a list. The standard given by user agent stylesheet is `list-style-type: disc;`.
Change the property to `list-style-type: none;` to get rid of the bullets.

```css
* {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    background:#b794e6ff;
}

h2{
    padding: 40px;
    background: #646ecb;
    color:#f0f1f5;
    font-family: fantasy;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30pt;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
}

.navbar {
    background: #fc575e;
    height: 40px;
    width:700px;
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13pt;
    color: aliceblue;
}

nav a:hover {
    background:#223423;
    color: #f0f1f5;
}


nav ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;  
}

nav ul li {
    float:left;
    width:140px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background:teal;
}

nav ul ul li{
    position: relative;
    display:none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/maintravel2.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
       
   
      
      <title>Round-a-Whirl</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div></div>
           <h2>HEADER LOGO</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"> Flights</i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-hotel"> Hotel</i></a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car"> Car Rental</i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"> Discover</i></a>
                    <ul>
                    <li>Vacation</li>
                    <li>Cruise</li>
                    <li>City</li>
                    <li>Nature</li>
                    <li>Getaways</li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tag"> Deals</i></a></li>
                
                </ul>

            </nav>
      </div>
        <article>
        This is a simple site I created using HTML and CSS of a travel site for the fictional Round-a-Whirl travel company.
        </article>
        <footer>
            Round-a-Whirl &copy; 2019
        </footer>
      

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```