# How do I align multiple lines in <li>

Tags: html, css

```html
<li>test<br />test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
```

How do I make the second line inside the first `<li>` to align with the first line?

I can't believe I'm asking this very basic question.

Comment: wow. i wonder why it receiving a down rate

Comment: do you want to make the <br> to aline with the first line <li>?

Comment: @ChrysUgwu yep, exactly...

Comment: y add <br> if you need them in same line?

Comment: @ChrysUgwu I need the 2nd line to line up with the 1st line, vertically, instead of it being under the bullet...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q0cu17ok/4/ simply missing `<ul></ul>` ?

Comment: its lined up vertically already. can you make an image of what u really want

Comment: @sdcr I wanna punch myself in the face. You should put it as answer, so you'd get the points or whatever... Thanks!

Comment: I pointed that out a half hour before.  By the way, you should have updated your question to explain that you wanted to suppress bullets.

Comment: @ThomasDickey oh, I didnt see your answer earlier..

Comment: No problem.  It might have been easier to read, except that I've not gotten the trick of inserting angle-brackets into text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example omits the open/close `ul` tags. With those, I would usually use a `p` to force a new line, but `br` works -- either would be aligned.

A followup comment asks for "no bullets".  That is answered in [Need an unordered list without any bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets)

Answer (score 0):

[There ya go](http://jsfiddle.net/cwxh4jyu/)

Simply nest an `li` inside the `li`

Answer (score 0):

Try this combination of CSS rules:

`text-indent: -1em;
padding-left: 1em;`

### EXAMPLE:

```css
li {
  text-indent: -1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<li>test
  <br />test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
```