# Remove bullet points in UL in CSS

Tags: html, css

I've followed the following tutorial in creating a simple menu bar which I place in a but can't seem to get my head round why the "list-style-type: none;" or "list-style: none;" won't work.

I've had a look at similar issues which seemed to be solved by ensuring overriding of the list styles in the nested OL isn't taking place but no luck on my side

[Example I looked at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets)

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

HTML:

```
<section class="menu_bar_section">
    <ul id="menu_bar">

        <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mauricii</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Periher</a>
            <ul class="noJS">
                <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tyrio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quicumque</a></li>

    </ul>
<section>
```

CSS:

```
 /* Section */
.menu_bar_section {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    color: #999999;
    background: #FFCC00;
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Tahoma, Sans-serif;
}

/* Structure
------------------------------------------*/
#menu_bar,
#menu_bar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#menu_bar {
    float: left;
}
#menu_bar > li {
    float: left;
}
#menu_bar li a {
    display: block;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu_bar ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
#menu_bar ul li a {
    width: 80px;
}
#menu_bar li:hover ul.noJS {
    display: block; 
}


/* Main menu
------------------------------------------*/
#menu_bar {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #2f8be8;
}
#menu_bar > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#menu_bar > li:hover > a {
    background: #f09d28;
    color: #000;
}


/* Submenu
------------------------------------------*/
#menu_bar ul {
    background: #f09d28;
}
#menu_bar ul li a {
    color: #000;
}
#menu_bar ul li:hover a {
    background: #ffc97c;
}
```

Comment: What element contain `menu_bar` id?

Comment: check this out... http://jsfiddle.net/comy91y4/

Comment: It is a problem if your `<ul>` don't have `id` you must have this one `<ul id="menu_bar"`

Comment: @DatzMe: The UL is associated with the menu_bar styling

Comment: @DatzMe: And I used an id on my UL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#menu-bar ul` will only target the `ul` which is a direct child of `#menu-bar`, the style wont propagate to nested `ul`'s within.

To target the nested ul you can either target it directly by it's class:

```
.noJS {
    list-style:outside none none;
}
```

or by drilling into the nested structure:

```
#menu-bar ul li ul {
    list-style:outside none none;
}
```

Comment: I followed your 'drilling' suggestion and it seems to work in removing the bullet points but i seemed to have messed up the listing of the nested LI. Here's my fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/03jqb9z2/embedded/result/

Comment: That is because they get `float:left;` from `#menu_bar li` (line 62 in the fiddle css). Just remove that, the top level menu items get it anyway from `#menu_bar > li` (line 14).

Comment: Thanks. You correction worked. Indeed I was applying 2 float:left stylings

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
list-style: none;
```

or

```
list-style-type: none;
```

Both of them works but the first is shorter but it gets the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
}
```

Or use like: (give id)

```
<ul id="menu_bar">
```

Check updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dxbh91m/1/) here.

```css
 <style>
.menu_bar_section {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    color: #999999;
    background: #FFCC00;
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Tahoma, Sans-serif;
}


#menu_bar,
#menu_bar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#menu_bar {
    float: left;
}
#menu_bar > li {
    float: left;
}
#menu_bar li a {
    display: block;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu_bar ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
#menu_bar ul li a {
    width: 80px;
}
#menu_bar li:hover ul.noJS {
    display: block; 
}



#menu_bar {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #2f8be8;
}
#menu_bar > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#menu_bar > li:hover > a {
    background: #f09d28;
    color: #000;
}


#menu_bar ul {
    background: #f09d28;
}
#menu_bar ul li a {
    color: #000;
}
#menu_bar ul li:hover a {
    background: #ffc97c;
}
</style>
```

```html
<ul id="menu_bar">
<li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mauricii</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Periher</a>
        <ul class="noJS">
            <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Tyrio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quicumque</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I attempted your above suggestion but no luck ... the bullet points still appear.

Comment: @kiberanumbanane Have you seen here by clicking on Run code snippet Or in JSFiddle. Or paste your code in JSfiddle and show us. Or show your whole code.

Comment: Have you add style tag properly. and Put css inside.?

Comment: sorry for earlier comment. an error on my part. using 124c41's suggestion I got rid of the bullet points but I seem to have messed about with the nested LI in the UL with the class noJS. Here's my fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/03jqb9z2/embedded/result/