# How to remove the dot from lists

Tags: html, css

Been working away, and I can not figure out how to get rid of the "." before list elements, I can change the color of them easily enough, but to turn them of on a list displayed in a column seems impossible.

This is the css in question:

```
.vert ul {
    line-style-type: none;
    content: " ";
    text-align: center;
    color: pink;
}
.vert ul:befor {
    content: " ";
    color: blue;
}
.vert li:before {
    content: " ";
    color: orange;
}
```

Any link that uses vert as class then ends up pink, and with a .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets

Comment: How does this question get 3 down votes without an explanation as to why? An honest mistake was made in the css and the mistake was pointed out. Problem solved. But down voting a question without a constructive explanation as to why you have done so creates a problem in that A. it discourages people from asking future questions while B. does nothing to help them answer their own questions in the future.

Answer (score 6):

`line-style-type` should be `list-style-type`.

Comment: Thank you very VERY much, and sorry for wasting your time :) (Feel a bit donutty now :) )

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
line-style-type: none
```

to

```
list-style-type: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
list-style-type: none;
```

to `ul` elements.