# Can't get bullets to hide on my ul

Tags: css

I can't seem to get my bullets/marks to hide from my menu bar on my site. I've tried using `list-style-type: none` but it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm a code newbie so any help would be of huge help! I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious. Best, E

```css
   

body {
     background: #262626;
     margin: 5px 0 15px 0;
     padding: 0;
     text-align: center;
     font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 75%;
     color: #333333;
}


/* Typography
------------------------------------------------------------------ */

#top p {
     font-size: 1em;
     line-height: 1.6em;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     color: #CCCCCC;
}

#header p {
     font-size: 1em;
     line-height: 1.6em;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}

#menu p {
     font-size: 1em;
     line-height: 1.6em;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}

#content p {
     font-size: 1em;
     line-height: 1.6em;
     margin: 0 0 15px 0;
     padding: 0;
}

#footer p {
     font-size: 1em;
     line-height: 1.6em;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     text-align: center;
     color: #CCCCCC;
}

#bottom p {
     font-size: 1em;
     line-height: 1.6em;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     color: #CCCCCC;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { 
     margin: 0  0 .6em 0;
     color: #333333;
     font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
     letter-spacing: -.06em;
     line-height: 1.1em;     
}

h4 {
     color: #cc0000;
     font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;

}

h1 { font-size: 2.2em; }
h2 { font-size: 3em;
 font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
 letter-spacing: .1em; 
 }
h3 { font-size: 1.8em; }
h4 { font-size: 2.1em; }
h5 { font-size: 1.4em; }
h6 { font-size: 1.2em; } 

#header h1 {
     padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
     margin: 0;
     font-size: 4.1em;
     font-family: 'Nosifer', cursive;
     color: #cc0000;

}

#header h2 {
     padding: 0px 0 0px 25px;
     margin-top: 15px;
     font-size: 2.2em;
     letter-spacing: 1.3px;
     color: #CCCCCC;
     font-weight: normal;
     font-family: 'Bangers', cursive; 
}
/* Hyperlinks
------------------------------------------------------------------ */

#top a:link {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}   
#top a:visited {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}  
#top a:hover {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: underline;}  
#top a:active {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}  

#header a:link {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}   
#header a:visited {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}  
#header a:hover {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}  
#header a:active {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}  

a:link {color: #CC0000; text-decoration: none;}   
a:visited {color: #CC0000; text-decoration: none;}  
a:hover {color: #CC0000; text-decoration: underline;}  
a:active {color: #CC0000; text-decoration: none;}  

#menu a:link {
     color: #FFFFFF; 
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 13.5px;
     margin:1px;
}   

#menu a:visited {
     color: #FFFFFF; 
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 10px;
     margin:1px;
}  

#menu a:hover {
     color: #111111; 
     text-decoration: none; 
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     padding: 10px;
     margin:0;
     border:1px solid #111111;
}  

#menu  a:active { 
     text-decoration: none;
}  

#COMPMENU a:link {
     color: #cc0000;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 13.5px;
     margin:1px;
}   

#COMPMENU a:visited {
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 10px;
     margin:1px;
}  

#COMPMENU a:hover {
     color: #111111; 
     text-decoration: none; 
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     padding: 10px;
     margin:0;
     border:1px solid #111111;
}  

#COMPMENU a:active { 
     text-decoration: none;
}  

#footer a:link {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}   
#footer a:visited {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}  
#footer a:hover {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: underline;}  
#footer a:active {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}  

#bottom a:link {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}   
#bottom a:visited {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}  
#bottom a:hover {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: underline;}  
#bottom a:active {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}  

/* Unordered Lists
------------------------------------------------------------------ */

#content ul, #bottom ul {
     margin-left: 0;
     padding-left: 0;
     list-style: none;
     font-size: 1em;
     line-height: 1.7em;
     margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

#content li, #bottom li  {
     padding-left: 12px;
     margin-bottom: .2em;
     background-image: url(../img/arrow.gif);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: 0 .5em;
}

/* Page Structure
------------------------------------------------------------------ */

#wrapper {
     width: 760px;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0 auto; 
     border: 1px solid #222222;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     text-align: left;
}

#top {
     width: 760px;
     margin: 0 auto; 
     padding: 10px 0;
}

#header {
     height: 255px;
     margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
     border: 0px solid #cccccc;
     background: black url(../img/header.jpg) top left no-repeat;
}

#menu {
     margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
     padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
     border-top: 1px solid #666666;
     background: #212121 url(../img/menu.jpg) top left repeat-x;
}

#menu_list {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     text-align: left;
}

#menu_list li
{
     text-align: left;
     font-size: 1.2em;
     font-weight: bold;
     display: inline;
     list-style-type: none;
     padding: 0 .9em 0 0em;
     margin: 0;
}

#content {
     margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
     padding: 20px;
     border: 0px solid #cccccc;
     background: #FFFFFF url(../img/sidebar.jpg) top right repeat-y;
}

#left {
     float: left;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     width: 480px;
}

#right {
     float: right;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 00;
     width: 180px;
}

#footer {
     margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
     padding: 20px 10px;
     border: 0px solid #cccccc;
     background-color: #9E0B0E;
}

#bottom {
     width: 760px;
     margin: 0 auto; 
     padding: 10px 0;
     border: 0px solid #cccccc;
}

.spacer { clear: both; }

#COMPMENU {
     margin: 0 3px 0 3px;
     padding: 5px 2.5px 5px 2.5px;
     border-top: 1px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     }

#COMPMENU_list {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     text-align: left;
     list-style-type: none;
     }

#COMPMENU_list li
{
     text-align: left;
     font-size: 1.9em;
     font-weight: bold;
     display: inline;
     padding: 0 .9em 0 0em;
     margin: 0;
     color: #cc0000;
     font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive; }


/* Images  
------------------------------------------------------------------ */

.photo_frame {
     float: right;
     padding: 5px;
     border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
     border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;  
     margin: 5px 0 10px 15px;   
}

.photo_frame img {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: 0;
}

.Fridaythe13th img {
     width: 190px;
     height: 280px;
}

figcaption {
     font-size: 60%;
     text-align: center;
     margin-top: .5em;}

    .SlasherCollage img {
     width: 425px;
     height: 319px;
     float: right;
     margin: 1.5em;}

    .Leatherface img {
     width: 425px;
     height: 319px;
     float: right;
     margin: 1.5em;}
```

```html
<div id="COMPMENU">
    <ul id="COMPMENU_list">
        <li><a href="killers.html">Killers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Terrible Place</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Weapons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Victims</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: show us your html code

Comment: <div id="COMPMENU">

<ul id="COMPMENU_list"><li><a href="killers.html">Killers</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Terrible Place</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Weapons</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Victims</a></li>
</ul></div>

Comment: Not sure what result you get but it works for me.

Comment: It's work to me, maybe another css style in your code replace this style. Try to change `list-style-type: none` to `list-style-type: none !important`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need an unordered list without any bullets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not bullets. You have an image set on your #content li, #bottom li styles. To not have it affect this list add  `background-image: none;` like this:

```
#COMPMENU_list li {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 .9em 0 0em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #cc0000;
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
  background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but he has also got it on each `li`: `#COMPMENU_list li`.

Comment: I've updated the post to include all my css. The snippet seems to show that everything is good, yet on my end I still get those pesky bullets. Any ideas?

Comment: I've put your code into a fiddle and there are no bullets: https://jsfiddle.net/q836088m/  Have you tried clearing your browser cache and re-loading the page?

Comment: Hi Leo, I've tried both. I keep getting those bullets. http://ericnolangonzaba.net/slasher/thefilms.html

Comment: The problem is caused by a background image on the #content li, #bottom li styles. To fix it add this to your #COMPMENU_list li   background-image: none;    -> I will update answer with correct advice.