# How to get rid of the dots on the side of list items?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have this problem where in the index page to show all my articles I get a dot on the very left side:

[image: dots on the left side]

If anyone knows how to get rid of the dots all help would be appreciated. Here is the source code for the page.

```
   <ul class="articles">
     <% @articles.each do |article| %>
      <li class="excerpt">
        <%= sanitize(truncate(article.body, length: 250)) %>
          <div class="read-more">
           <%= link_to "Read more", article_path(article), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
      </li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're using an `<li>` element, which by default comes with nasty bullet points. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets) - add this to your CSS:

```
ul.articles
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bullet point, as part of a list.  That makes sense, since you're rendering it in an unordered list.

If you want that to go away, it's a CSS style change in your `articles` class.

```
.articles {
    list-style-type:  none;
}
```