# How to suppress bullet points in HTML list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

```
<ul>
<li>(a) mines, quarries, and other works for the extraction of minerals from the earth;</li>
<li>(b) industries in which articles are manufactured, altered, cleaned, repaired, ornamented, finished, adapted for sale, broken up or demolished, or in which materials are transformed; including shipbuilding and the generation, transformation and transmission of electricity or motive power of any kind;</li>
<li>(c) construction, reconstruction, maintenance, repair, alteration, or demolition of any building, railway, tramway, harbour, dock, pier, canal, inland waterway, road, tunnel, bridge, viaduct, sewer, drain, well, telegraphic or telephonic installation, electrical undertaking, gas work, water work, or other work of construction, as well as the preparation for or laying the foundations of any such work or structure;</li>
<li>(d) transport of passengers or goods by road, rail, or inland waterway, including the handling of goods at docks, quays, wharves or warehouses, but excluding transport by hand.</li>
</ul>
```

I have the above `HTML`.  What `CSS` coding can I add above this `HTML` that will suppress the bullet points generated by the `<li>` tags?

Comment: `ul { list-style:none}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need an unordered list without any bullets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets)

Comment: Refer to this answer on the question mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1027367/2555668

Answer (score 1):

Try following in your `HTML`, which will hide `bullets` of `<li>`:

```
<style>
    ul {
      list-style: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: How do I add this to the HTML? I am new to CSS.

Comment: This is fantastic.  Thanks for your help.