# Removing black dots from li and ul

Tags: html, css

Im working on a project and im using some ul and li's.

But i cant seem to figure out how to remove those pesky black dots that come with those lists.

Can any of you help me with this?

Edit: i completely forgot to search this site if there was already an answer (derp) turns out there was! Marked this as a duplicate, thanks for helping me everyone!

Comment: I have to agree with you @catzilla There seem to be alot of questions regarding the removal of bullets.

Answer (score 374, accepted):

[Relatable post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets)

Those black dots you are referencing to are called bullets.

They are pretty simple to remove, just add this line to your css:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 24):

There you go, this is what I used to fix your problem:

**CSS CODE**

```
nav ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Milk</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Goat</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Cow</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Eggs</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Free-range</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Cheese</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Smelly</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Extra smelly</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 20):

**CSS :**

```
ul{
list-style-type:none;
}
```

You can take a look at [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp)