# CSS get rid of list points by id of form

Tags: html, css

I have code from my former colleague for a login form. There are list points and I either want them

- to be white and not red or
- gone for just this login form

[login form problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8EPu.jpg)

The css file is huge and with dev tools of my browser I figured out the relevant css part. But first the html:

```
<div id="content" class="">
<form id="fuLoginForm" class="InputfieldForm ng-pristine ng-valid" name="fuLoginForm" method="post" action="./" data-colspacing="1">
    <ul class="Inputfields">
        <li class="Inputfield InputfieldText Inputfield_username ui-widget InputfieldStateRequired" id="wrap_username">
           <div class="InputfieldContent ui-widget-content">
             <input id="username" class="required InputfieldMaxWidth" name="username" type="text" maxlength="2048" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>     
</form>
```

This is the relevant css:

```
#right-sidebar ul > li::before, #content ul > li::before{
content: "▪ ";
padding-right: 10px;
color: #B41F2A;
}
```

This is what I tryed so far to test it. But I cannot select just the list point. Is there a way to overlay the complete line with white?

```
li[id="wrap_username"] {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

The points are used in other pages, too. And if I consider `content`other pages will be affected, too. The points must be red in other pages but as I mentioned not in this login form. And I don't know why me former colleague did it this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing black dots from li and ul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350948/removing-black-dots-from-li-and-ul)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type ?

Comment: maybe : `li#wrap_username { list-style: none; }` ?

Comment: @HastaDhana unfortunatelly not. I can change the background-color with your code and so one but not the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can make out of your question, you don't want to display the square bullets for this particular form.
You can override the pseudo elements for this particular form.

```
#fuLoginForm > ul > li::before{
  content: none
}
```

Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/v8j16xdt/8/

Comment: Thank you this solved my probelm. The other pages seem not to be affected. Thank you :).