# How do I remove the numbers in an HTML ordered list ('ol')?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a portfolio site together, and I need help in using the flexslider. I tried using it, but there is something wrong in my CSS part that is preventing my page from rendering properly.

[image]

Comment: Please show us code. We can't help you if we can't see the code you are using.

Comment: Some context not provided in *any* of the answers: [list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) - *"none. No item marker is shown."*"

Comment: Or [I need an unordered list without any bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1027354)

Answer (score 25):

Try it:

```css
ol li{
  list-style-type: none;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>1.1</li>
  <li>2.2</li>
  <li>3.3</li>
  <li>4.4</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40670629/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 7):

Use

```css
ol li{
  list-style: none;
}
```

or

```css
ol li{
  list-style: none!important;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include a little bit more explanation in your answer: not just the code, but what the code *means* and why it answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using CSS:

```css
ol li{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ol>
```