# Looping Array which is inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, javascript-objects

I have an object named myInfo

```
var myInfo = {
            skills: ['PHP', 'Java', 'JavaScript', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'jQuery'],
            languages: ['English', 'German']
            }
```

And I want to loop over the strings inside the `skills` array which is inside the `myInfo` object. I've tried this but doesn't seem to work

```
        var mySkills = '';
        for (i=0, i < myInfo.skills.length, i++) {
          mySkills += 'li' + myInfo.skills + 'li';
        }
        document.write(mySkills);
```

Any help will be appreciated. Maybe I went wrong somewhere in the code.

Comment: Three errors. Firstly for uses `;` in between the options instead of `,`. Second, you're not using the i, so isntead of `myInfo.skills` should be `myInfo.skills[i]`. Thirdly, if you want to use strings to create new `li` do `<'li>' + myInfo.skills + '</li>'

Comment: `var mySkills = myInfo.skills.map(skill => 'li' + skill + 'li')` will  produce: ["liPHPli","liJavali"...]. _Since this was marked as duplicate, I couldn't post an answer. Also, note that "[Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)," the `(skill) => 'li' + skill + 'li'` part (short for `function(skill){ return 'li'+skill+'li' }`) won't work in IE (of course), but will work in Edge, for what it's worth._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need to access the index as well, you can use `for.. of`

```js
var myInfo = {
            skills: ['PHP', 'Java', 'JavaScript', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'jQuery'],
            languages: ['English', 'German']
            }
            
for (let skill of myInfo.skills)
{
  console.log(skill);
}
```

If you do need to access the index and you don't want to write a long `i=0; i < length; i++` you can use `for... in` instead

```js
var myInfo = {
            skills: ['PHP', 'Java', 'JavaScript', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'jQuery'],
            languages: ['English', 'German']
            }
            
for (let index in myInfo.skills)
{
  console.log(myInfo.skills[index], "at index", index);
}
```

Comment: OP appears to be attempting to concatenate an `html` string.

Comment: @guest271314 that's true, and there's a problem there as well

Comment: Easiest Approach! I used the let of loop worked fine. But do you have any idea why it outputs so make dots? http://prntscr.com/emy0uh


                                       for (let skill of myInfo.skills)
     {
       document.write('<li>' + skill + '<li>'); 
     }

Comment: @KautilyaKondragunta Because it's an li. It will default to dots unless you apply a css to them, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets Also, why use `li` if you don't want the dotting?

Answer (score 2):

I would write a routine which creates an `li`:

```
function li(content) {
  const elt = document.createElement('li');
  elt.innerHTML = content;
  return elt;
}
```

Now, create a **document fragment** to put all those `li`s into, based on an array:

```
function makeLis(contents) {
  const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

  contents.forEach(content => frag.appendChild(li(content));
  return frag;
}
```

Write a function to create a `ul` element to put the `li`'s into:

```
function makeUl(contents) {
  const ul = document.createElement('ul');

  ul.appendChild(makeLis(contents));
  return ul;
}
```

Now you can write that into your document:

```
document.getElementById('target').appendChild(makeUl(contents));
```

Answer (score 1):

get the values of skills through index

```
var mySkills = '';
for(i=0; i < myInfo.skills.length; i++) {
    mySkills += '<li>' + myInfo.skills[i] + '</li>';
}
document.write(mySkills);
```

Comment: That seems to be one of the few errors i have in the code. Still outputs an error when i tried logging it to a console.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: @Chinito Use `;` in `for(i=0, i < myInfo.skills.length, i++) {` instead of `,`.

Comment: oh. yeah. maybe that's your error. use semicolon instead of a comma. i just copied your code though. thanks @Tushar

Comment: Yeah that was the error , works now . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can access an individual object in the Object Array through index [].
The objects are 0 index based.

```
skills: ['PHP', 'Java', 'JavaScript', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'jQuery'],
```

PHP is the start of the object array, at position 0

```
mySkills += '<li>' + myInfo.skills[i] + '</li>';
```

`i` will increment for every pass until,

```
for(i=0; i < myInfo.skills.length, i++) {
```

`i` is greater then the `length` of the array, 0,1,2,3,4,5.

a semi-colon is required when initializing the variable.

Comment: [Repeating same mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942437/looping-array-which-is-inside-an-object#comment72981483_42942454)