# Remove list bullets from <ul>

Tags: html, css

Can you help me how can i delete this purple thing?
I tried to add padding 0px; in css containers but it didn't work.

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13wXt.png)

Comment: add to your css code : ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need an unordered list without any bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add via inline style,

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
```

or via your css style sheet, this will remove the bullet from all ul

```
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
</style>
```

if you wish to affect only a specific list, you can add an id and hide it

```
<ul id="testul">

<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
</style>
```

You can also add the following as well to remove indentation.

```
<style>
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; 
}
</style>
```