# Change navbar list bullet in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, navbar, bootstrap-4

How would I go about modifying the CSS to delete the bullet I got for every item menu of the navbar Bootstrap 4/Jhipster? Now there's both the bullet and the picture `<i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>` and I want to delete the bullet. This is the code snippet:

```
<nav>
    <div class="jh-logo-container float-left">
        <a class="jh-navbar-toggler d-lg-none float-right" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" (click)="toggleNavbar()">
            <!--<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>-->
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbarResponsive" [ngSwitch]="isAuthenticated()">
        <ul>
             <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/" (click)="collapseNavbar()">
                    <span>
                        <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span jhiTranslate="global.menu.home">Home</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: do you mean `list-style: none;` of `ul`?

Comment: Yes, I do. The exact syntax for Bootsrap 4 is: <ul class="list-unstyled">. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Find a solution from here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets

Answer (score 0):

For Font Awesome you should use its built in way to do lists with icons.

*Example:*

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>can be used</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>as bullets</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-square"></i>in lists</li>
</ul>
```

Check the [docs](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#list) for more info.