# how to have un-bulleted items in same list as bulleted items

Tags: html, html-lists, unordered

I know how to create an unordered list in HTML. Below is a basic construct. However, I need to have a list that will have both bullets and non-bullets within the same div section. Second item below is the desired result.

```
 <div class = "dropdown menu"
 <ul class = "bullet">
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example2</li>
 <li>Example3</li>
 </ul>
 </div>



 - first item
 - second item
 - Third item
       Call xyz for details
 - 4th Items
       Call abc for details
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets Does this help?

Comment: @MarkHollis, can I have two list styles embedded in the same actual list. I know how to designate the style at the beginning but changing the style in the middle is not so clear

Comment: It's not possible, I googled it and nothing came up.

Comment: @MarkHollis. Ok, Well, I will just have to think of another way to do this. If I was to put another div (and corresponding /div between the third and fourth item, would it mess it up?

Comment: Only one way to know for sure

Comment: https://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479461 CRTL+F "Can I put these together?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without bullets, but you can indent normally like so:

```
<OL>
<LI>Main Heading
<UL>
<LI>List item 1
<LI>List item 2
</UL>
<LI>Secondary Heading
<UL>
<LI>List item 1
<LI>List item 2
</UL> 
</OL>
```

1. Main Heading

   - List item 1
   - List item 2
2. Secondary Heading

   - List item 1
   - List item 2