# Change ordered list's appearance by defining new css rules

Tags: css

Suppose such a minimal snippet retrieved from database,

```
<ol>
    <li>Moview</li>
    <li>Music</li>
    <li>Drama</li>
</ol>
```

It displays as

1. Moview
2. Music
3. Drama

I need to deactivate the linenums and the padding, shown as:

Movie
Music
Drama

Since the source data is inaccessible, is it possible to achieve it by define new css rules on ol?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need an unordered list without any bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `list-style-type` property to `: none;` on your ordered list and add `padding:0;` to remove indentation.

```css
ol.style {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;}
```

```html
<ol class="style">
    <li>Moview</li>
    <li>Music</li>
    <li>Drama</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Don't forget `padding:0`

Comment: It'd be more efficient to add the class to the `ol` then do `ol.style li`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets) post has a comment explaining that setting `list-style-type: none;` on `ol`/`ul` doesn't work in IE9. Instead it has to be set on the `li`. `margin: 0;` will have to be set on both `ol.style` and `ol.style li`.