# Unable to use CSS to style an unordered list as a navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

```css
.navbar {
    background-color: 595959;
    color: #ffffff;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class = "navbar"> 
    <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Our Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Donate</a></li>
</ul>
```

No matter what I do in my CSS stylesheet to style the navbar nothing changes. In the code above I tried to remove the bullets with the list-style however nothing changes as shown in the photo. It seems no css commands are making any difference on the unordered list.

[image]

Comment: of course the code i have included is not together on a html file. i have imported my stylesheet and the css code is in the stylesheet which is definitely imported into the index.html file correctly.

Comment: You can start with `ul.navbar li { display: inline-block; }`

Comment: or maybe your stylesheet link is incorrect or has the wrong path, maybe absolute v. relative, but you're not showing that. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/your.css">`

Answer (score 2):

Here we go please dot his like this to archive style for removing the bullets use `list-style-type:none;` and of you do not want to use flex property you can simply use `.navbar > li{display:inline-block;}`

```css
.navbar {
    background-color: 595959;
    color: #ffffff;
    list-style: none;
    display:block;
}

.navbar{display:flex; list-style-type:none;}
.navbar li{display:block; padding:15px;   border:1px solid #000;  color:#fff; }
.navbar li a{width:100%; text-align:center; color:#000;  text-decoration:none; }
.navbar2P{list-style-type:none;}
.navbar2 li{display:inline-block; }
.navbar2 li a{display:block; border:1px solid #000; color:#000; padding:15px 5px; text-decoration:none; }
```

```html
<ul class = "navbar" > 
    <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Our Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Donate</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class = "navbar2" > 
    <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Our Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Donate</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i have added another navbar in my code please check it it will help you more .

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1027367/10720231):

> You can remove bullets by setting the list-style-type to none on the CSS for parent element (typically a ), for example:
>
> ```
> ul {
>   list-style-type: none;
> }
> ```
>
> You might also want to add padding: 0 and margin: 0 to that, if you want to remove indentation as well.
>
> See [Listutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/index.htm) for a great walkthrough of list formatting techniques.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just add another CSS class:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the result you need if you add:

```
display: block;
position: relative;
```

If it doesn't help - please make some sandbox in jsfiddle or alike resource and give a link, let's see what's wrong.

If you need to style **li** and **a** elements, you need to write as well, for example:

```
.navbar li{
list-style: none;
padding: 1vw 2%;
}
.navbar li a{
text-decoration: none;
}
```