# How to make a navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I want to make a navigation menu for my website, but it doesn't work.
Here is the code I actually have

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav > ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav > ul > li{
    float: left;
}

nav li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="mnav"><a href="main.html">Acceuil</a></li>
            <li class="mnav"><a href="bio.html">Biographie</a></li>
            <li class="mnav"><a href="folio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="mnav"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

I want to make the li point not visible.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets

Comment: A simple example can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style_none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #fcfcfc;
    color: #fcfcfc;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.nav {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
}

.nav-brand {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-items {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-item {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

.nav-item:hover {
    color: orange;
}


.nav::after {
    display: table;
    content: '';
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Nav Bar</title>
</head>

<body>
 <ul class="nav">
        <div class="nav-brand">
            Brand
        </div>
  <div class="nav-items">
            <li class="nav-item">Home</li>
            <li class="nav-item">About</li>
            <li class="nav-item">Blog</li>
            <li class="nav-item">News</li>
        </div>
 </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use CSS property, `list-style-type: none;` in `nav > ul > li`.
Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Inline CSS :

```
<li style="list-style-type: none;">
```

Or select the Ul with any class name you prefer. Here i used 'menu' as a class of ul.

```
.menu li{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS property:

```
a {text-decoration: none;}, nav li:hover{background: yellow;}, nav li{list-style-type: none;padding: 10px; background: red; float: left;}
```

Result after applying the CSS:

[image]

Hope it works fine. You can refer at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp