# How to remove point from li tag

Tags: html, css

How to remove point from li tag?
so that only the title remains

```
 <ul>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>about</li>
    <li>contact</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: What is `point`? also, there is no title in your code.

Comment: just add the css `ul{list-style-type:none}` , now the dot is disabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need an unordered list without any bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this example at w3school. 
Just add to your CSS

```
ul{list-style-type:none};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a CSS class for that
This should resolve the problem:

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
```