# Remove dots from list in CSS

Tags: html, css

How to remove dot from "add recipe"? when i try it does not work...

html:

```
<div id=menu>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="add_recipe">Add recipe</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
#menu
ul > li
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Read this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp

Comment: ul parent, li child... i just sow it somewhere.  I tried only ul li but it does not work as well...

Comment: i does not help still does not work when  put ul li ...

Comment: Is this answer to your question? [html - I need an unordered list without any bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1027354/4061713)

Comment: no i have made it like this it does not help. I have to remove it form li so i have #menu ul li, but it does not work..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're referring to the "bullet point" marker, then it did work when I ran the code without changing anything. Are you sure it isn't working when you run it? Have you tried clearing the cache to make sure the old script isn't running?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id=menu>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="add_recipe">Add recipe</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: it does not work for chrome.. i guess it will later... thanks for your time :)

Comment: I ran it on chrome as well. It's working there as well

Comment: did you try it in chrome?

Answer (score 1):

but your code as written works fine in chrome

```css
ul 
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div id=menu>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="add_recipe">Add recipe</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry i see something wrong with chrome and it does work for explorer f.e. i think probably chrome will get it later..

Comment: what do you see that's wrong?

Comment: in chrome it doesn not work yet, but i thinl it will be later

Comment: i run it on chrome now it works fine.  There's some thing else in your code that's not working.  check console log for errors

Comment: it works in explorer but not in chrome. i do not know what this console is

Comment: in chrome go to your web page and right click on it. Select inspect. a new window will open. Click on the console tab and see what it says.  report back

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Check for overrides if it doesn't work (you can use computed styles on the dev tools)

list-style-type can be added to the parent element (<ul> in this case) as child elements (<li>) inherit properties unless they're defined.

```css
#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div id=menu>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="add_recipe">Add recipe</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

More reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type