# Issue with Removing Bullets on UL LI

Tags: css, html-lists

```
<div class="menu-editor-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-editor-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-292" class="AdminMenu menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-292">
<a>Welcome,  John Doe</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

In this instance I want to remove the bullet points that appear before the 
`<li>`, but not everywhere else in the site, for the life of me I cannot get them to go away using CSS. Ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need an unordered list without any bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/i-need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets)

Answer (score 1):

You need `list-style: none`.

To target just this list use a selector that is specific enough, for example, just this menu:

```
#menu-editor-menu {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Or even just this one list item:

```
#menu-item-292 {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So Simple, Hope it helps. Thanks.

```css
.menu-editor-menu-container ul{
  list-style: none;
  /*Optional*/
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-editor-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-editor-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-292" class="AdminMenu menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-292">
      <a>Welcome,  John Doe</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```