# Remov bullets from Django MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-forms

Im trying to figure out how to remove bullets from Django's `MultipleChoiceField`. So far I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/i-need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets) very popular solution by changing my css file that basically states to input this code in my css file

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

This didnt work and I also tried:

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

This also didnt work. Is there something Django specific why the list keeps on showing up with bulletpoints? I also tried adding the style in my forms class but also without success

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    job_industry = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-check', 'style': 'list-style:none;'}),
        choices=industry,
    )
```

I noticed that whatever attrs I enter to the `forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple` it only gets passed to the `<label>` tag and not the `<ul>` or `<li>` tag of the list. Im using Bootstrap5 if that makes any difference.
How to delete bulletpoints from Django `forms.MultipleChoiceField`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be because of cache. Previously I set up memcache and had set the `'TIMEOUT': None` Thats the reason why changing the css didnt have no effect