# remove bullets from unordered list using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am trying to remove the bullets showing in the unordered list using bootstrap. I have tried the "text-decoration-none" class but no use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17596978/7845355

Answer (score 9):

try like this:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add type attribute in ul tag and set the value none

```html
<ul type=none>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Voluptatum culpa iure temporibus quisquam.</li>
  <li>Dolor enim quas sint iusto.</li>
</ul>
```

You can do this by css by the following code -

```css
  ul{
    list-style-type: none;
  }
```

Comment: no i dont want to use css..just bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You can try this CSS

```
ul, li {list-style-type: none;}
```

It will globally removed bullets from the unordered list. you can use specific class.

Comment: no I just want to use bootstrap no CSS